# Python's Selenium won't execute remaining code once I "go back" a webpage

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am VERY new to Python. I need to scrape data from a website, but the code isn't seeming to working. Well, the first half and the second half of the code work just fine on their own. The problem is that those two pieces of code are connected by the action of going *back* a webpage, and it doesn't matter if I use driver.back() or driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")--the second half of the code always fails. I bold that line of my below code for convenience. Anyone have any tips on how I can make Selenium keep doing its thing instead of failing halfway-through? Thanks! (Yes, my code is really clunky but I'm just a beginner!)

Here is my code:

```
#Calling to use Chrome to webscrape
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/myuser/Documents/chromedriver.exe")
  
#Getting link
driver.get("https://www.fec.gov/data/committee/C00716720/?cycle=2020")

#From committee webpage: Look up committee browse receipts, then click "Download" and download said receipts

try:
    sleep(randint(3,8))
    
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Browse receipts"))
        )
    element.click()
    
    sleep(randint(10,15))
    
    element2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main"]/section/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/button'))
        )
    element2.click()
    
    sleep(randint(5,7))
    
    element3 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div/ul/li/div/a'))
        )
    element3.click()

    **driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")**

    sleep(randint(3,8))
     
    element4 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
         EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Browse disbursements"))
         )
    element4.click()
     
    sleep(randint(10,15))
     
    element5 = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
         EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main"]/section/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/button'))
         )
    element5.click()
     
    sleep(randint(5,7))
     
    element6 = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
         EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div/ul/li/div/a'))
         )
    element6.click()

except:
     print("You failed.")
```

Comment: try/catch this:    element4 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
         EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Browse disbursements"))
         )  and include the exception thrown in your post.... if no exception happens, try/catch the element4.click() part and post that exception.  Btw, you don't need any of those sleeps... the webdriverwait will sleep as long as needed...

Comment: pcalkins--thanks for this advice. Just for clarity, you mean to first try the element4 command with the exception to print "You failed", and then if that element4 works, try it again with element4.click? element4.click is the part that fails, and it still does with these edits.

Comment: We just need to see the exceptions you are getting from Selenium.  So try/catch the those individual calls and include the exception(s) in your post.  "You failed" doesn't tell us much... (sry, I'm not familiar with Python, but I think to catch you'd want "except SomeError as err: " then you can output "err" and that should be the exception?)

Comment: Off topic but,using absolute Xpaths may not be ideal